# Gate::define with constructor parameter in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel Policy and Gate.

i need to have `__construct($id)` in policy.

My policy:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Button;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class BotPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        #First Step
        $this->bot = Bot::findOrFail($id);


        #Second Step
        if ( $this->bot->hasRole('admin') )
            return true;


        #Third Step
        if ( $this->bot->status != 1 )
            return false;
    }


    public function button(?User $user, $id)
    {
        #Fourth Step
        if ( $this->bot->account()->max >= $this->bot->button()->count() )
            return true;

        #Fail
        return false;
    }

}
```

My Controller:

```
    public function create()
    {
        if ( Gate::denies('bot-button', request('id') ) )
            echo "NO";

        #SOME CODE HERE


    }
```

AuthServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('bot-button', 'App\Policies\BotPolicy@button');
```

But for the this code in policy

```
  public function __construct($id)
```

I give this error

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $id ]] in
>   class App\Policies\BotPolicy

Answer (score 1):

Firstly constructors is not a method you can return properties with, it is simply a method that is called on newly created objects, often to set properties and similar.

I believe your policy can be written like so, by moving the `__constructor` logic to the policy method. Thereby removing the __constructor all together, in `Laravel` if dependency injection is loaded like so, it will try to create constructor parameters in the container.

```
public function button(?User $user, $id)
{
    #First Step
    $this->bot = Bot::findOrFail($id);

    #Second Step
    if ( $this->bot->hasRole('admin') )
        return true;

    #Third Step
    if ( $this->bot->status != 1 )
        return false;

    #Fourth Step
    if ( $this->bot->account()->max >= $this->bot->button()->count() )
        return true;

    #Fail
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I cant see why you need that logic in the constructor, if it's need to be there, please explain why.